# API Gateway Request Mapping, How to check string length

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I am trying to get a string length so that I can check it size here is the sample of the code any ideas would be great.
[Sample of what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSSSa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you get the string length:

```
#set($test = $inputRoot.DoNotDisturbRequest.doNotDisturbRoomId.length())
```